# Integrating LDAP and Kerberos V to add users via a useradd-like interface

Tags: administration, kerberos, openldap

I'm currently trying to set up an integrated Kerberos V/LDAP system for authentication/authorization. From what I have managed to gather, there are at least two ways to integrate Kerberos V with LDAP:

1. Use LDAP as a backend to store Kerberos principals
2. User Kerberos and SASL authentication via GSSAPI to authenticate to the LDAP server (to be able to query and modify the LDAP entries using a Kerberos ticket)

The two options aren't mutually exclusive. The thing is, I would like to make a hybrid of the two: not just use LDAP to store Kerberos principals, but also make sure that when I add a Kerberos principal, it's created with `objectClass=posixAccount` in order for it to appear as a Unix user entry to NSS for authorization purposes.

To paraphrase, I would like to have to add new user accounts in only one place  (*viz.*, the `kadmin` server) instead of two. Is this possible? If so, how?

If it's any help, I'm using OpenLDAP and MIT Kerberos on Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody answered this question and I found no existing solutions to this, I [rolled my own solution](https://github.com/Joseph-Riad/usertools) in Perl. The solution is geared towards Debian specifically because this is my target environment. Feel free to fork it and adapt it to your needs.

Your comments on the code/coding style would be very appreciated. Feel free to tear it to shreds: I'm not a developer by training and I'm relatively new to scripting administrative tools.